# How to calculate the accuracy limit for a particle in 1-dimensional closed box? Recursive systems. Heisenberg Uncertainity Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Assume a particle in a closed box. Both the particle and the box are confined to single direction/dimension. The cases are:

1. The potential energy of the walls are infinite.
2. The potential energy of the walls are not infinite, but high... moderately high... higher than low.

For the situations above, while talking about the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, do we only deal with what is inside the box or do we take "box" position and momentum into account too? In other words, what is the accuracy limit for the particle according to an observer out of the box, $\frac{h}{4\pi}$ or $\frac{h^2}{16\pi^2}$ or something else ? Also what is the case for recursive systems, i.e. particle inside box inside box inside box etc. ?

As a side question, is it possible that we know both the exact position and the exact momentum of a particle "relative to the system" which is in -even though we cannot make much use of this information as the whole system is still subject to HUP in the universe?

Comment: The 'box' isn't being treated as a quantum object, it's just an external classical field.

Comment: @jacob1729 But the borders also should be subject to the uncertainty principle, shouldn't they?

Comment: *But the borders also should be subject to the uncertainty principle, shouldn't they?* In what way?

Comment: *Also what is the case for recursive systems, i.e. particle inside box inside box inside box etc. ?* A particle in a box with infinitely high and strong walls is contained completely within these walls. No amount of additional walls around the 'inner' box changes anything to that.

Comment: @Gert 1. Can we measure where the walls are exactly? If we can, then we do not know the momentum of the walls. Both seems (I don't know) to have an affect on the wave-function of the particle inside. 2. Each box has their own wave-function inside another box, i.e. each box is like a particle in a 1-dimensional box.

Comment: The $P1DB$ example assumes the walls are undeformable and unmovable. The box itself is not a quantum object. There's NO uncertainty re. its position.

Comment: @Gert Ok, here is the chance to inspect a more complicated scenario :P

Comment: *2. Each box has their own wave-function inside another box, i.e. each box is like a particle in a 1-dimensional box.* Nope, that's just not how the box thought experiment is set up.

Comment: You can however put a number of boxes with **finite** walls 'in series'. That system would have one wave function only.

Comment: Bloch wave function: http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss1/bloch/blochwave.php